# Codename One Overflow menu set scrollabel to false

Tags: menu, codenameone

I have several commands added to an overflow menu.

When running the app, the overflow menu is scrollableY and has a scrollbar on the right. The effect looks kind of odd in my app.

I have tried to access the menu via hi.getToolbar(). ..., but there seems to be no method to get the overflow menu directly.

How can I turn the scroll effect and the scrollbar off in the overflow menu?

Thanks in advance for any kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like something we should fix. We already did a similar fix for the side menu with the theme constant `sideMenuScrollVisibleBool`. We should probably disable the visibility of the scroll here by default too. This should be easy but due to the code freeze I can't do this right now.

Please file an issue and we'll try to address it after the release: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new